# Gtest EXPECT_DEATH() fails with SIGABRT

Tags: c++, ubuntu, gitlab, googletest, sigabrt

I'm testing an assertion with `EXPECT_DEATH()` and it fails on Ubuntu (gitlab ci pipeline) with `killed by signal 6 SIGABRT`. However, exact same code works fine on Windows.

Afaik, this macro is specifically designed to handle exit with error codes.

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"

class MyDeathTest : public ::testing::Test {
 protected:
 ...
};

TEST_F(MyDeathTest, TestNegative1) {
  EXPECT_DEATH(assert(false), "");
}
```

I've tried to use `EXPECT_EXIT(assert(false), ::testing::KilledBySignal(SIGBART)), "");` instead and `::testing::ExitedWithCode(6)`, as well as `EXPECT_DEBUG_DEATH()`, `EXPECT_DEATH_IF_SUPPORTED()` etc. with no luck.

Also, i've tried to set `GTEST_FLAG_SET(death_test_style, "threadsafe");` but got `error: 'GTEST_FLAG_SET' was not declared in this scope;`

Any suggestions on fix?

Comment: Could you please add a minimal and reproducible example?

Comment: The given example is enough to reproduce. It looks like it just doesn't work as expected on the OP's Ubuntu OS.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things:

1. You should use `SIGABRT`, not `SIGBART`
2. Looks like the google test release that you are using is old and doesn't have the `GTEST_FLAG_SET` macro yet. You can use this as an alternative:

```cpp
(void)(::testing::GTEST_FLAG(death_test_style) = "threadsafe");
```

Working example: https://godbolt.org/z/15azKeMG4

From [googletest docs](http://google.github.io/googletest/faq.html#my-death-test-hangs-or-seg-faults-how-do-i-fix-it)

> In googletest, death tests are run in a child process and the way they
> work is delicate. To write death tests you really need to understand
> how they work—see the details at Death Assertions in the Assertions
> Reference.
>
> In particular, death tests don’t like having multiple threads in the
> parent process. So the first thing you can try is to eliminate
> creating threads outside of EXPECT_DEATH(). For example, you may want
> to use mocks or fake objects instead of real ones in your tests.
>
> Sometimes this is impossible as some library you must use may be
> creating threads before main() is even reached. In this case, you can
> try to minimize the chance of conflicts by either moving as many
> activities as possible inside EXPECT_DEATH() (in the extreme case, you
> want to move everything inside), or leaving as few things as possible
> in it. Also, you can try to set the death test style to "threadsafe",
> which is safer but slower, and see if it helps.

So I would say first make sure you are using the latest release, and secondly try with `threadsafe`.